# Kubernetes: Multiple Services/Replication Controllers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We're looking for direction on how to set up services and replication controllers for multiple microservices. I see a lot of examples on the internet that demonstrate a single service; I'm not sure how to configure each service separately. Are there examples out there that anyone can point to?

Answer (score 1):

The [Guestbook example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/examples/guestbook-go/) shows a multi-tier web application that uses multiple services and multiple replication controllers.